# How to get the width of an EditText widget in Android in EM units

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an EditText widget defined with a fixed size (using dp units).
How can I retrieve the width in EM units?

I'd like to change the hint text based on the calculated size.

Thanks

Comment: I'm stuck with the same issue, have you solved it somehow?